# vertical menu bar handling for responsive screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a vertical nav bar and when screen size becomes less than `1000px` it will collapse. I have issues here. I need my vertical bar as size of my page as well when collapse button occur , when I click the button , i need to call the vertical menu bar as i given in big screen , but here it coming as dropdown. Need guidance.[My code is present in plunker here](http://jsfiddle.net/WSRMP/144/)

http://jsfiddle.net/WSRMP/144/

I need this way like mentioned in http://d.pr/i/17DfQ in left side of my screen

Comment: Please post code here - create a [mcve]

Comment: It would be better if you can paste a shorter code here. Like @Archer said: Minimal,Complete and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ul to this:

```
<ul class="styleUl"  style="height:100vh;display:table;">
```